# Expand Widget inside a SingleChildCrollView

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/domain/entities/entities.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/presentation/riverpod/league_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/presentation/riverpod/search/search_form_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/presentation/riverpod/team_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/presentation/widgets/search/card_search_team.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/presentation/widgets/general_appbar.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/presentation/widgets/search/filter.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/presentation/widgets/search/not_found.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';


class SearchTeamView extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const SearchTeamView({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<SearchTeamView> createState() => _SearchTeamViewState();
}

class _SearchTeamViewState extends ConsumerState<SearchTeamView> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final SearchFormState form = ref.watch(searchFormProvider);
    final List<Team> teamList = ref.watch(teamProvider.notifier).getTeamsByLeague(form.league);
    
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: GeneralAppBar.getAppBar('Equipos', () => context.pop()),
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Form(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
              
                    //* League
                    const SizedBox(height: 15),
                    const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: Text('Liga', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),),
                    ),
                    Filter(
                      hint: '-- Sin Especificar --',
                      listForm: [
                        '-- Sin Especificar --', 
                        ...ref.watch(leagueProvider.notifier).getLeaguesByAll(form.league, form.season, form.category, form.sex, form.delegation)
                      ], 
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        value == '-- Sin Especificar --'
                        ? ref.watch(searchFormProvider.notifier).leagueChanged(null)
                        : ref.watch(searchFormProvider.notifier).leagueChanged(value);
                        setState(() {});
                      },
                      value: ref.watch(searchFormProvider).league,
                    ),
                  ]
                ),
              )
            ),

            Expanded(child: Text('Hola'))        
            
          ],
        ),
      ),
      
    );
  }
}
```

The goal is to have the 'Hello' widget expand to the full height of the screen, but I'm running into the following problem:

Se produjo una excepción. FlutterError (RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded. When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height constraint, for example if it is in a vertical scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis. Setting a flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to fill the remaining space in the vertical direction. These two directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to shrink-wrap its child, the child cannot simultaneously expand to fit its parent. Consider setting mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min and using FlexFit.loose fits for the flexible children (using Flexible rather than Expanded). This will allow the flexible children to size themselves to less than the infinite remaining space they would otherwise be forced to take, and then will cause the RenderFlex to shrink-wrap the children rather than expanding to fit the maximum constraints provided by the parent. If this message did not help you determine the problem, consider using debugDumpRenderTree():   https://flutter.dev/debugging/#rendering-layer   http://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/debugDumpRenderTree.html The affected RenderFlex is:   RenderFlex#94345 relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE(creator: Column ← _SingleChildViewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#259a7] ← Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#b6d4e] ← Listener ← _ScrollableScope ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#7a2d1] ← NotificationListener<ScrollMetricsNotification> ← Transform ← ⋯, parentData: <none> (can use size), constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity), size: MISSING, direction: vertical, mainAxisAlignment: start, mainAxisSize: max, crossAxisAlignment: center, verticalDirection: down) The creator information is set to:   Column ← _SingleChildViewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#259a7] ← Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#b6d4e] ← Listener ← _ScrollableScope ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#7a2d1] ← NotificationListener<ScrollMetricsNotification> ← Transform ← ⋯ The nearest ancestor providing an unbounded width constraint is: _RenderSingleChildViewport#234a8 relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE:   needs compositing   creator: _SingleChildViewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#259a7] ← Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#b6d4e] ← Listener ← _ScrollableScope ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#7a2d1] ← NotificationListener<ScrollMetricsNotification> ← Transform ← ClipRect ← ⋯   parentData: <none> (can use size)   constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=675.4)   size: MISSING   offset: Offset(0.0, -0.0) See also: https://flutter.dev/unbounded-constraints If none of the above helps enough to fix this problem, please don't hesitate to file a bug:   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.yml)

The problem is when I decide to expand a widget inside a SingleChildScrollView as it occupies an infinite height.

I hope you can help me to solve the problem

I hope you can help me to solve the problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter SingleChildScrollView with Expanded column child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63540425/flutter-singlechildscrollview-with-expanded-column-child)

Answer (score 0):

here is your answer:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/domain/entities/entities.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/presentation/riverpod/league_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/presentation/riverpod/search/search_form_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/presentation/riverpod/team_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/presentation/widgets/search/card_search_team.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/presentation/widgets/general_appbar.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/presentation/widgets/search/filter.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/presentation/widgets/search/not_found.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

class SearchTeamView extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const SearchTeamView({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<SearchTeamView> createState() => _SearchTeamViewState();
}

class _SearchTeamViewState extends ConsumerState<SearchTeamView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final SearchFormState form = ref.watch(searchFormProvider);
    final List<Team> teamList =
        ref.watch(teamProvider.notifier).getTeamsByLeague(form.league);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: GeneralAppBar.getAppBar('Equipos', () => context.pop()),
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Form(
              child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child:
                Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
              //* League
              const SizedBox(height: 15),
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Text(
                  'Liga',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 20),
                ),
              ),
              Filter(
                hint: '-- Sin Especificar --',
                listForm: [
                  '-- Sin Especificar --',
                  ...ref.watch(leagueProvider.notifier).getLeaguesByAll(
                      form.league,
                      form.season,
                      form.category,
                      form.sex,
                      form.delegation)
                ],
                onChanged: (value) {
                  value == '-- Sin Especificar --'
                      ? ref
                          .watch(searchFormProvider.notifier)
                          .leagueChanged(null)
                      : ref
                          .watch(searchFormProvider.notifier)
                          .leagueChanged(value);
                  setState(() {});
                },
                value: ref.watch(searchFormProvider).league,
              ),
            ]),
          )),
          const Expanded(
              child: Text(
            'data',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40, color: Colors.white),
          ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: And if inside the Expanded instead of a Text there was a ListView.builders

Comment: @AntonioDiaz set list view